# Windows command: concatenate variable in for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'd like to concatenate variable in for loop.
Here is my code.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions

SET Task=A
echo dosomething %Task%


SET List=B C

for %%i in (%List%) do (
    SET Task=%Task%, %%i
    echo complete list %Task%
)
```

I expect the output is:

```
complete list A, B
complete list A, B, C
```

However, the result is:

```
D:\Desktop\Test>(
SET Task=A, B
 echo complete list A
)
complete list A

D:\Desktop\Test>(
SET Task=A, C
 echo complete list A
)
complete list A
```

Do anyone have a solution?

thanks!

Comment: Type `for /?` at the command prompt and just copy the example below "delayed expansion"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`, don't forget to replace the percent signs with exclamation marks in the code block. If not, it doesn't update the process.

Comment: You mean the *percent signs* rather than *ampersands*, right??

Comment: @aschipfl Oh Thanks, I didn't notice that!

Comment: To be clear, you have to change the "SET Task=%Task%, %%i" to "SET Task=!Task!, %%i".